# Tolerance for 'ipopt' optimizer

Tags: pyomo

Is there any way to adjust the tolerances for the '*ipopt*' optimizer that is used in *Pyomo*?

Answer (score 5):

The default tolerance for Ipopt is 1E-8. This can be changed from Pyomo using the solver-specific 'tol' option. For example:

```
solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
solver.options['tol'] = 1E-5
solver.solve(model)
```